# Objective-C: Check IP connection

Tags: objective-c, sockets, connection

I am facing a problem to check a local IP connection.

I am using this project https://github.com/pbkhrv/SimpleSocketConnection to check an IP with a port.

This work fine when I want to connect one IP:

```
[[NetworkController sharedInstance] connect:@"192.168.1.100"];
```

But when I want to check many connections like that:

```
for(int i=1; i<255; i++) {
     NSString *ip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.%d", i];
     [[NetworkController sharedInstance] connect:ip];
}
```

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: "Does not work" is a little vague.  What are you expecting to happen?  What isn't happening?  Are their error messages?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some more information on asking good questions.

Comment: I am trying to check many connections , if connection with ip exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController ()
- (void)displayMessage:(NSString*)message;
@end


@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)displayMessage:(NSString*)message {
  // These two came from UITextView+Utils.h
  [textViewOutput appendTextAfterLinebreak:message];
  [textViewOutput scrollToBottom];
}


#pragma mark - Public methods

- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {

    for(int i=1; i<255; i++) {
        NSString *ip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.%d", i];
        [[NetworkController sharedInstance] connect:ip];
    }


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Enable input and show keyboard as soon as connection is established.
  [NetworkController sharedInstance].connectionOpenedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection){
    [textInput setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [textInput becomeFirstResponder];

      NSLog(@"Connection opened");

    [self displayMessage:@">>> Connection opened <<<"];
  };

  // Disable input and hide keyboard when connection is closed.
  [NetworkController sharedInstance].connectionClosedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection){
    [textInput resignFirstResponder];
    [textInput setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self displayMessage:@">>> Connection closed <<<"];
  };

  // Display error message and do nothing if connection fails.
  [NetworkController sharedInstance].connectionFailedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection){
    [self displayMessage:@">>> Connection FAILED <<<"];
      NSLog(@"Connection failed");
  };

  // Append incoming message to the output text view.
  [NetworkController sharedInstance].messageReceivedBlock = ^(NetworkController* connection, NSString* message){
    [self displayMessage:message];
  };
}
```

This is the